# PHP, Mysql only update columns that exist in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a terrible way to write code but based on the clients situation, I'm wondering if there is a way to update columns in a database that exist and just do nothing with the other ones.

We have a query that's being generated and some of the columns are legit and will update just fine however some of the columns don't exist so when it tries to update it it fails. Is there anyway to update the records that do exist and throw away the other ones?

I really can't think of a simple way of doing this =/

Comment: Without a more detailed explanation and some example code it's hard to understand exactly what you're looking for or what the problem is. How's the query being generated? Do you mean rows rather than columns?

Comment: Agreed. Ordinarily, you'd just say which columns to update and the others won't be touched.

Answer (score 2):

You can query `information_schema.COLUMNS` table to get all columns for a given table. Then, you can modify your algorithm that generates update query to exclude all non-existing columns.